# JSON Deserialize different named object into a Collection c#

Tags: c#, json, collections, deserialization

I have to read a given JSON string into C# objects. So far so good but this case is kind of special to me. The JSON string contains 2 entities. One is a flat object and the second is a list, logical at least but not really in JSON. I hope you can help me finding a solution to this.

To explain it better i will show you a part of my JSON input:

```
{
"game":{"GameMode":"1","IsNetworkMode":"1","NbMaxPlayer":"12","GameState":"1"},

"player_56":{"PlayerUserId":"137187","PlayerIALevel":"-1","PlayerObserver":"0"},
"player_7":{"PlayerUserId":"3440","PlayerIALevel":"-1","PlayerObserver":"0"}
}
```

I want to serialize the Player entities into a collection of objects of this type. The Problem is that they arent really stored as a collection in JSON. They have dynamic names as "player_56" and the number is not in any logical order like "1,2,3".

At the moment I am using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` for this task.

```
[DataContract]
public class AlbReplay
{
    [DataMember(Name = "game")]
    public AlbGame Game { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "player")]
    public List<AlbPlayer> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have tried this so far:
    [DataContract]
    public class AlbReplay
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "game")]
        public AlbGame Game { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "player")]
        public List<AlbPlayer> Players { get; set; } 
    }

Comment: Do you have control over this JSON?  Ideally you need to get an array of players.  Dynamic properties is not very helpful!  You could serialize to a dynamic object and just look for properties starting with "player" but this isn't very nice.

Comment: No unfortunately, not. If there is no other option i have to go for something like this, thank you so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the extent of `DataContractJsonSerializer`, but there might be an interface you can implement on your class to define how to parse the JSON.

But if you're able to use [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlayerUserId { get; set; }
    public int PlayerIALevel { get; set; }
    public int PlayerObserver { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use Linq-To-JSON:

```
var data = @"{
""game"":{""GameMode"":""1"",""IsNetworkMode"":""1"",""NbMaxPlayer"":""12"",""GameState"":""1""},

""player_56"":{""PlayerUserId"":""137187"",""PlayerIALevel"":""-1"",""PlayerObserver"":""0""},
""player_7"":{""PlayerUserId"":""3440"",""PlayerIALevel"":""-1"",""PlayerObserver"":""0""}
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

IEnumerable<Player> players =
    o.Children()
    .Where(p => ((JProperty)p).Name.StartsWith("player"))
    .Select(p =>
        new Player
        {
            Id = int.Parse(((JProperty)p).Name.Split('_')[1]),
            PlayerUserId = int.Parse((string)p.Children<JObject>().First()["PlayerUserId"]),
            PlayerIALevel = int.Parse((string)p.Children<JObject>().First()["PlayerIALevel"]),
            PlayerObserver = int.Parse((string)p.Children<JObject>().First()["PlayerObserver"]),
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Mangle your JSON into a collection of player objects.

```
player_8: {...}
player_99: {...}
```

to

```
players: [
    {id: 8 ...},
    {id: 99 ...}
]
```

How to mangle your JSON, a RegEx would likely be sufficient.

**EDIT** Here's code for the string mangling using Regex. A few assumptions were made: there are no objects embedded inside of the game and player objects and the player object list is the last part of the json string.

```
        string json_test = @"{
""game"":{""GameMode"":""1"",""IsNetworkMode"":""1"",""NbMaxPlayer"":""12"",""GameState"":""1""},
""player_56"" : {""PlayerUserId"":""137187"",""PlayerIALevel"":""-1"",""PlayerObserver"":""0""},
""player_2"":  {""PlayerUserId"":""137187"",""PlayerIALevel"":""-1"",""PlayerObserver"":""0""}
}";
        json_test = new Regex(@"""player_(\d+)""\s*:\s*{").Replace(json_test, @"""player"" : {""Id"": $1,");
        Console.WriteLine("player_##:{...} -> player:{id: ##,..}");
        Console.WriteLine(json_test);
        json_test = new Regex(@"""player""\s*:\s*{").Replace(json_test, @"""players"" : [{", 1);
        json_test = new Regex(@"""player""\s*:\s*{").Replace(json_test, @"{");
        json_test = new Regex(@"}$").Replace(json_test, @"]}");
        Console.WriteLine("player:{...}, -> players: [{...},...]");
        Console.WriteLine(json_test);
```

As with all considerations regarding speed, you'll have to test it out, having the Regex objects as static and reusable would be my first step if I had to optimize the above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well if there is no other way, i have to go for some string operations before the De-serialization. Odd thing is that i have to do this with quite a lot of files. I fear my performance :)

Comment: @John Smuf - Working with that kind of JSON is always an issue, it needs to be transformed at some point. I added the Regex replaces for your specific case to my answer. Another thing you could try is .NET's dynamic object then you could cast to a Dictionary<string, object> and cast all of the objects with a key that begins with player_ to the Player class, not sure if it would work or even be faster though.